# Trouble using require vs import React Native

Tags: import, react-native

I recently purchased a tutorial on Udemy to learn react native. Some of the code is deprecated. I am truly trying my best to make work past these issues.  The problem I have is I am unable to import a file using require.

```
My import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';
import weekdays from './src/day-item';



var Weekdays =React.createClass({
    render:function(){
      return <View>
      <Text>
        Days of the Weeks:
      </Text>
      </View>
    }

});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('HelloWorld', function(){

  return Weekdays


});
```

The error message I am receiving is "Requiring unknown module "day-item".

Day item code looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';




var  DayItem =React.createClass({
    render:function(){
      return <View>
      <Text>
        Days of the Weeks:
      </Text>
      </View>
    }

});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('HelloWorld', function(){

  return Weekdays


});

module.exports = DayItem;
```

The tutorial instructs me to use this syntax for importing a file:

```
var DayItem = require('./src/day-item');
```

This code also yields me the same error message I mentioned up above. I searched the internet and could not find a solution to my problem. I think the concept is important and I would like to know the proper way of importing files to keep my code clean.

Comment: Your path in the import is just wrong. What is the location of the day-item module relative to the calling code?

Comment: it is in the src directory

Comment: I have even copied the file in the same directory to remove complication and still no luck.

Comment: I created an img to help http://imgur.com/a/mLNwf

Comment: @RobertMoskal any idea on where I went wrong?

Comment: If you use default react native packager, try use a path relative to project's root folder, like `HelloWorld/src/day-item`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so I tested it on my own, only inputting the code from the index file and the day-item file, and it seems to work fine for me:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4V4N.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QD7nk.png

The only thing I changed was in the index file, where I changed your AppRegistry to the name of the project only. That might be where your issue lies.

Also in your comment of your original post, you posted a picture of your code. When importing a file from the same folder, you still have to use './', so your code should be

```
var DayItem = require('./day-item');
```